# VBA Adjusting for last row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook in which I have created a macro for 9 different worksheets and while working properly I want to be able to add code for the **last row** So I can either Insert or Delete rows depending on need. I was able to do this for one worksheet but have an issue when I apply the same technique for others. What could be the issue with applying the code to multiple worksheets? The top portion of the code is what I am attempting to use to assign the last row function and the bottom is a sample worksheet I am attempting to add last row code.

```
Dim LastRowT As Long, LastRowS As Long
Dim wks1    As Worksheet
Dim wks2    As Worksheet

Set wks2 = Workbooks("UMROI_Standard Cost Audit Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review")
Set wks1 = Workbooks("before_n_after_remap_audit_umroi.txt").Worksheets("before_n_after_remap_audit_umro")

LastRowS = Workbooks("before_n_after_remap_audit_umroi.txt").Worksheets("before_n_after_remap_audit_umro").Range("A:E").Find("*", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
LastRowS = Workbooks("before_n_after_remap_audit_umroi.txt").Worksheets("before_n_after_remap_audit_umro").Range("F:G").Find("*", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
LastRowT = Workbooks("UMROI_Standard Cost Audit Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review").Range("A:E").Find("*", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
LastRowT = Workbooks("UMROI_Standard Cost Audit Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Before n After Remap Review").Range("I:J").Find("*", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row


Range("A9:F147").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    "K:\1900\dwprod1900\data\export\general\ent_component_audit_umroi.txt", Origin _
    :=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote _
    , ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:= _
    False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1) _
    , Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A1:F139").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("UMROI_Standard Cost Audit Reports.xlsm").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
 Windows("ent_component_audit_umroi.txt").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.Close
```

Comment: "*… but have an issue when …*" is a completely useless error description as you can imagine. Be detailed in what is working and what is going wrong. Do you get any errors if so which errors and in which line of code. Describe what your code does and what you expect (**be very exactly**). If possible provide a [mcve]. Please [edit] your original question to improve it and add all the details.

Comment: Agree with Peh. Many questions are thrown in without much detail and a LOT of code. The asker is then expecting a complete and error-free code on reply.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, it was hard when thinking about asking the right way. My goal is to be able to adjust for the table in my worksheet data needing more or less rows based on the lastrow of the new source data. I have had some success working the code since I posted this I will post a more clearer follow up soon.

Comment: @HazatBangurah You still only tell us what you want/need, but that's not what we need to know. We need to know what is not working in your code that you have tried. If we don't know what's wrong then we can't tell you how to correct it.